# Scrollable table and keydown function

Tags: jquery, scrollable, jquery-scrollable, scrollable-table

I have a program at [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/PhillipSenn/gDh9K/1/), which uses the webtoolkit jquery plugin to make a table be scrollable.  It works for IE and FF, but not Chrome.  I'm not worried about it not working in Chrome.  My problem is that I'm giving the user the ability to use their arrow keys to move to the selected cell.

Q: How do I scroll the table if the user presses the down arrow key too many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollable thing in Chrome is a problem with the plugin and not something you can fix. However the way you are scrolling when the arrow keys are pressed is undesirable. You should only scroll the table if the selected cell is in some way obfuscated. For example is you go one cell below the visible area.

Comment: I agree.  I just don't know the mechanics of how to fire an event to make the table scroll.

Comment: You can scroll the table by scrolling the tables `tbody` element@ `$('table tbody').scrollTop(10);`